# how to change the value as 0 when we have more than 10 digit in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have scenario like below..

I have column that has value like 12345678900.5555 and -12345678900.2582, I need to change the values   to  0 because these column having more than 10 digit before dot(.). could help for this scenario...

```
 Item Values          return Values
  12345678900.5555        0
 -12345678900.5555       0
  123456789.00          123456789
  1234567890.00         1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic:

IIF(Item_value>9999999999 OR (Item_value<0 AND Item_value<-9999999999),0,Item_value)

Answer (score 0):

Get the number divided in whole number and decimal number.
If the count of whole number is greater than 0 it should be replaced with zero.

V_whole= SUBSTR( number,1,INSTR( number,'.' ,-1,1 ) - 1 ) 
V_decimal=SUBSTR(number,INSTR(number,'.',1,1)+1)

Iff(count(V_whole)>,0,V_whole)